# Angular orderBy number sorting as text in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this data:

```
[{"id":"42","firstname":"Sarah","lastname":"Dilby","age":"40","cars":"Yaris"},
{"firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Diry","age":"5","id":"5"},
{"id":"6","firstname":"Bilson","lastname":"Berby","age":"1","cars":"Tipo"}]
```

When I orderBy id or by age in an ng-repeat, it sorts the number as text. Since I can't find it written that this is an issue anywhere, I'm guessing there's a problem with my code. I have created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vsbGH/1/ Sorry about the template, but jsfiddle doesn't allow  in the html box. Anyway, this is the code which loads and sorts the data:

```
//user data
app.service('People', function() {
var People = {};
People.details = [{"id":"42","firstname":"Sarah","lastname":"Dilby","age":"40","cars":"Yaris"},
                  {"firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Diry","age":"5","id":"5"},
                  {"id":"6","firstname":"Bilson","lastname":"Berby","age":"1","cars":"Tipo"}]
return People;
});

//list ctrl
controllers.listCtrl = function ($scope,People) {
 $scope.people = People.details;

 $scope.sortList = function(sortname) {
    $scope.sorter = sortname;
 }
}
```

And this is the ng-repeat part of the template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:sorter ">
        <td>{{person.id | number}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstname}} </td>
        <td>{{person.lastname}} </td>
        <td>{{person.age | number}}</td>
        <td>{{person.cars}} </td>
 </tr>
```

Many thanks if you can help me understand why the number data isn't sorting as numbers, and why it's sorting as text.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think the most appropriate solution is to format the numbers I have on my JSON objects correctly, ie not to wrap them in quotes. So:

```
 [{"id":"42","firstname":"Sarah","lastname":"Dilby","age":"40","cars":"Yaris"},
  {"firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Diry","age":"5","id":"5"},
  {"id":"6","firstname":"Bilson","lastname":"Berby","age":"1","cars":"Tipo"}]
```

becomes:

```
[{"id":42,"firstname":"Sarah","lastname":"Dilby","age":40,"cars":"Yaris"},
 {"firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Diry","age":5,"id":5},
 {"id":6,"firstname":"Bilson","lastname":"Berby","age":1,"cars":"Tipo"}]
```

I'm guessing SergL's solution is good if it's not possible to correct the format of the JSON data.

To add to this, the issue in my specific case is to do with PHP's json_encode function on the server side. By default, it treats numbers as strings. To fix I had to add the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option to the encode method in the PHP script:

```
json_encode($assoc_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: I just had to do the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK thing today as well. Nice.

Comment: I used `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` first time and its just awesome.

Comment: JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is amazing.  That worked like a charm, thanks @dewd !

Comment: FYI JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, can break stuff too. It removes leading zeros. eg. phone number, 0401231234 becomes 401231234.

Comment: @Firze I never consider phone number as a "number" it should always remain a string.

Comment: This post just keeps giving even 5 years later.  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK for the win.

Answer (score 31):

You don't have to modify your JSON. You can pass a function to orderBy filter like this:

```
$scope.sorterFunc = function(person){
    return parseInt(person.id);
};

<tr ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:sorterFunc ">
        <td>{{person.id | number}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstname}} </td>
        <td>{{person.lastname}} </td>
        <td>{{person.age | number}}</td>
        <td>{{person.cars}} </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: how do I order by descending ?

Comment: To order by descending you can add a - before parseInt(): return - (parseInt(person.id)); or even better, you can add a parameter to the sorterFunc, to specify the sort type ASC or DESC

Comment: how did person get passed here

Comment: @Omar, whatever function you name in the Angular HTML, in this case "sorterFunc", ng-repeat calls that function with its parameter set to the value of that instance of the repeat.  So since it says:
ng-repeat="PERSON in people | orderBy : sorterFunc",
when sorterFunc is called the value of "person", on that iteration of ng-repeat, is sent as its parameter.

Comment: Or to put it another way, the "|" (pipe) character is saying take the output of the expression on the left, and pass it through the thing on the right. The output of the left, on each iteration, is a single value of person.

Answer (score 15):

Inside your ng-repeat directive you are using a number filter

```
<td>{{person.id | number}}</td>
```

Filters are used to format the output, but they don't update the Model properties. For example: person.id = 1234.56789 will be rendered as 1,234.568.

As mentioned above you have to convert age to type Number. Then orderBy will work as it should.
For example inside your service:

```
angular.forEach(People.details, function (detail) {
  detail.age = parseFloat(detail.age);
});
```

Comment: @SergL I've just twigged that in the angular docs example, the numbers in the JSON data are not wrapped by quotes. I'm guessing this is what I should do with my JSON data.

Answer (score 5):

*if your orderBy value is not a variable pointing to another string* but rather the attribute by which you'll be sorting, you must put it in quotes.

```
person in people | orderBy:'-id'
```

If, after you've parsed your int or float and are still not sorting correctly, it might be because of this. <:/  (that's my dunce cap)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem when I was working with a text field and ngModel to change the value of the model I was ordering by. Because the value was regarded as string.

With new HTML5 [`<input type="number" />`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D), Angular parses the value of the input field to a number (float I think), which helped me to get the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Let `orderBy` point to a method owned by the scope or its not isolated ancestors and let this method return a number casted from the string.
You may have to write a directive inheriting the `person` scope created by the ngRepeat instances.. to add this method.

Moreover in your case, the age is a string where it could have been an integer and so the numeric sort would be natively applied.

If you cannot change the data serverside then alter it clientside while fetching.

Answer (score -1):

It is best to update your repeating collection whenever a sort function is called. Here I am using [Lodash - orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy) just to order the collection based on a sorter function. Lets say the sort is called on click of table column head.

Example:

Collection object:

```
ctrl.people = [{"id":"42","firstname":"Sarah","lastname":"Dilby","age":"40","cars":"Yaris","salary": 700}, {"firstname":"Jason","lastname":"Diry","age":"5","id":"5","cars":"Lexia","salary": 500},{"id":"6","firstname":"Bilson","lastname":"Berby","age":"1","cars":"Tipo","salary": 400}];
```

User clicks column head to sort by age:

```
<th class="col-age" data-ng-click="ctrl.sortColumn('age')">Age</th>
```

Method called:

```
ctrl.sortColumn('age'); // where age is column containing numbers only
```

Method implementation:

```
ctrl.sortedCol = 'firstname';    //Default sort column

ctrl.sortColumn = (column) => {
    ctrl.sortedCol = column; //age
    let order = 'asc'; //you can decide the order based on your own logic
    ctrl.people = _.orderBy(ctrl.people, [ctrl.sorter], [order]);   //update the collection
};

ctrl.sortColumn(ctrl.sortedCol); //called on initial rendering
```

Sorter function: Returns the sorted collection based on column type

```
ctrl.sorter = (item) => {
    const columnType = ctrl.getColumnType();
    if(item[ctrl.sortedCol] && columnType === 'string'){
        return item[ctrl.sortedCol].toLowerCase();
    } else if(item[ctrl.sortedCol] && columnType === 'number'){
        return parseInt(item[ctrl.sortedCol]);
    } else{
        return item[ctrl.sortedCol];
    }    
};
```

Decide column type: Can be string, number or even date

```
ctrl.getColumnType = () => {
    if(ctrl.sortedCol === 'firstname' || ctrl.sortedCol === 'lastname' || ctrl.sortedCol === 'cars'){
        return 'string';
    } else if(ctrl.sortedCol === 'salary' || ctrl.sortedCol === 'age'){
        return 'number';
    }
};
```