# ng-repeat ordering wrong

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON containing details about photos, I want to order the repeater according to the id contained into the JSON:

```
ng-repeat="photo in photos | orderBy:'id'"
```

But the resulting order is like this:

```
1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2 [..]
```

How can I fix this ordering issue?

**Update: Solution**

Even if the answer provided below, are all working, the best solution for me has been provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770797/850134):

Adding `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` when encoding the JSON in my PHP script, did the trick.

Comment: the obvious solution is to convert the `id` values to numbers instead of strings before iterating over it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular orderBy number sorting as text in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764177/angular-orderby-number-sorting-as-text-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes, the solution to his problem is my exact same solution. Sorry, I did searched before asking, but I missed this one.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a custom function to use for the ordering..

```
   $scope.integerId= function(photo) {
       return parseInt(photo.id, 10);
    };
```

and use it as

```
ng-repeat="photo in photos | orderBy:integerId"
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MvQK6/

Answer (score 0):

I believe like it has already been stated this happens because your photos' ids are interpreted as String, thus the orderBy filter is doing a lexicographical sort.

To fix this you have to transform your ids into number. What you can do is create a new filter that will transform the id into number :

```
angular.module('my.filters', []).filter("idToNumber", [function() {
    return function(value) {
        return value.map(function(item) {
            item.id = parseInt(id, 10);
            return item;
        );
    }
}]);
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
ng-repeat="photo in photos | idToNumber | orderBy:'id'"
```

Comment: `parseInt(value.id, 10)` Always specify the radix. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: This is the right route for sure, but now `1 2 3 4 5` have moved to the end, after `48` (that is the last entry)

Comment: `idToNumber` receives the array as its `value` arg, so your example cannot work.