# How to sort table list as per requirement using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to sort the table list using Angular.js but it's not happening like that. My code is below:

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="c in clickSummary | orderBy:['-total','+rest_name']">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td>{{c.rest_name}}</td>
  <td>{{c.page_hit}}</td>
  <td>{{c.map_hit}}</td>
  <td>{{c.gallery_hit}}</td>
  <td>{{c.phone_hit}}</td>
  <td>{{c.web_hit}}</td>
  <td>{{c.total}}</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
```

Here I need to sort the list as per `total and rest_name filed`. I need to sort as per total column value in descending order and if there are same value in total column then it should sort as per `rest_name`. But in my case I am getting the output like below.

[image]

In this picture you can see one has total column value `11` but it's coming last which should come fast.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764177/angular-orderby-number-sorting-as-text-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

It is sorting by string comparison rather than number comparison. That means you're not presenting the data as numbers.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)