# AngularJs: not ordering numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have a problem when ordering my list in ng-repeat, is sorting, however, the numbers from 1 to 9 are in dozens positions for example:

```
89
9
90
91...
```

I'm ordering like this:

```
Ng-repeat = "object in arrayfinal | filter: q | orderBy: '- duv_codigo'"
```

[image]:

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764177/angular-orderby-number-sorting-as-text-in-ng-repeat#16770797

Comment: seems like the orderBy is more like a "string" order, and not a number order. numbers would be 9 89 90 91, but for string its completly correct what we see in your example. Check how this orderby function works

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK.