# Ideas on Angularjs OrderBy with numbers? 10 is considered less than 2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have messages sorted by their index.  Messages 1 - 9 are ordered properly, 1 being at top, 9 being at the bottom.  Obviously you want the latest message on the bottom.

10 however, due to the 1, is dropped below 2.  I tried making 100001, 100002, etc. but 100010 does the same thing.

I would like a way to index the messages in my Database, and when they're arrayed in Angular, have them sorted by their index, but numerically, it's not working!

Angular:

```
orderBy:'msg_index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:
[Angular orderBy number sorting as text in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764177/angular-orderby-number-sorting-as-text-in-ng-repeat)

Or else Convert msg_index to INT using function parseInt()

Comment: Which programming languages do you use to expose your database data?What format does the data display?

Comment: I use PHP to grab a multidimensional array from the mysql db, and then return it to the angular controller as JSON

Comment: add this SON_NUMERIC_CHECK as sencod argument of json_encode.

Comment: If you don't use json_encode i need to see the code

Comment: I do.  I also solved the issue, with your suggestion, somewhat.  I looped through the multidimensional array, parsefloated, added a -index predicate to my sorting in the ng-repeat, and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Angular, but you've tagged this with PHP. PHP has a "natural" sort which returns entries ordered in the way you're describing.

See [PHP natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).