# How to orderby number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[My plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BNzJyUr0tRauA7tbIUfr?p=preview)

In this plunker based on orderby in ng-repeat it is working fine but when the rowId exceeds 9 number in parent `+` button, the rowid becomes `10`.

The parent rowid `10` is displaying as a child of `1`.

Here I am separating parent and child with `-`.
If the rowid is child then I am adding `-` before child record.
Finally what I want to achieve is I want to display `10` as parent, `1-10` as child.

```
    var newRow = {
    "rowId": "1",
    "componentIdentification": "",
    "componentName": "",
    "codigo": "",
    "componentType": "",
    "componentState": "",
    "actionId": "",
    "actionPerform": ""
  }
  $scope.componentList = [];
  $scope.componentList.push(angular.copy(newRow));

  $scope.addParentRow = function(rowId) {
    var newGridRow = angular.copy(newRow);
    var lastChar = getListOfSameLevel(rowId, true); //isParentRow
    var parentId = rowId.length > 1 ? rowId.slice(0, rowId.length - 1) : "";
    newGridRow.rowId = parentId + getNextChar(lastChar); 
    $scope.componentList.push(newGridRow);
  }

  $scope.addChildRow = function(rowId) {
    var newGridRow = angular.copy(newRow);
    var lastChar = getListOfSameLevel(rowId, false);
    if (rowId.length === lastChar.length) {
      newGridRow.rowId = rowId + "-1";
    } else {
      var parentId = lastChar.length > 1 ? lastChar.slice(0, lastChar.length - 1) : "";
      newGridRow.rowId = parentId + getNextChar(getLastChar(lastChar));
    }
    $scope.componentList.push(newGridRow);
  };

  var getNextChar = function(inputChar) {
    return parseFloat(inputChar) + 1;
  };

  var getLastChar = function(fullStr) {
    return fullStr.slice(-1);
  };

  var getListOfSameLevel = function(rowId, isParentRow) {
    var compIdLength = rowId.length;
    var matchedArray = [];
    var sortedMatchedArray = [];
    var latestCompId = "";

    if (compIdLength > 1) {
      var parentId = isParentRow ? rowId.slice(0, rowId.length - 1) : rowId;
      if (!isParentRow) {
        matchedArray = _.filter($scope.componentList, function(row) {
          return ((row.rowId.length >= compIdLength) && row.rowId.startsWith(parentId));
        });
      } else {
        matchedArray = _.filter($scope.componentList, function(row) {
          return ((row.rowId.length === compIdLength) && row.rowId.startsWith(parentId));
        });
      }

      sortedMatchedArray = matchedArray.sort();
      latestCompId = sortedMatchedArray[sortedMatchedArray.length - 1].rowId;
      return isParentRow ? getLastChar(latestCompId) : latestCompId;
    } else {
      matchedArray = _.filter($scope.componentList, function(row) {
        return (row.rowId.length === compIdLength || (!isParentRow && row.rowId.startsWith(rowId)));
      });
      sortedMatchedArray = matchedArray.sort();
      latestCompId = sortedMatchedArray[sortedMatchedArray.length - 1].rowId;
      return latestCompId;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Again same code!!!!

Comment: Code is same But the problem is different

Comment: @Murali that is because your id is a string, not a number

Comment: is there any way to convert it into int

Comment: @Murali see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944596/3153169), but better would be to let your id be in fact a number, not a string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a result of you sorting on rowID as a string, instead of rowID as a number.

I've added a function to return the integer value of rowID and then sort on that. It places the 10th row at the correct place in the list (after 9, not after 1), but stops incrementing at 10, so you've got other issues there you'll have to figure out.

Basically you add this function:

```
  $scope.rowIdAsNumber = function() {
    return parseInt(rowId.to);
  };
```

And then change your repeat to orderBy that function

```
  <tr data-node="treetable-1" id="basetr10" name="0" ng-repeat="rowData in componentList | orderBy:'rowIdAsNumber'">
```

I've forked your plnkr here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Q4aQTU5CzVJ7EPUuEY4s?p=preview

Comment: One small change: `'rowIdAsNumber'` shouldn't be in quotes

Comment: Check the plnkr - it doesn't work without the quotes.

Comment: it should come as a parent but it is adding as a child and if I add any other childs those are adding in the last

Comment: You're likely using rowID as a string elsewhere in your code where you should be using it as a number. Strings sort 1 10 100 2 20 200 not 1 2 10 20 100 200, so that's the fundamental issue. Go through your code and see where else you're making use of rowID as a string that breaks after 9.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith let me check

Comment: @StephenR.Smith I have modified `parentId + getNextChar(lastChar)` to `parseFloat(parentId + getNextChar(lastChar))` like this it is working but the childs are adding in the last