# sort floats in angularjs (ng-repeat) in Angular-DataTables

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angular-datatables

I am using angularjs v1.4.0

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764177/angular-orderby-number-sorting-as-text-in-ng-repeat/23899838#23899838) topic  but the correct answer doesn't work for me.

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6)
    .withOption('type', 'number')
    .renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
        if (type == 'sort') {
            var value = data.match();
            value = parseFloat(value[0]);
            return value.toString().length != data.length ? value+0.0001 : value;
        }
        return data
    })
];
```

If i use this code:

1. My sort is for the first 3 digits.
2. I can't use stoppropagation in the table.

Comment: Which version of Angular-Datatables are you using?

Comment: angular-Datatables v0.5.2 use my project.